# The site ahead contains malware Attackers currently on magento

Tags: magento-1.9, security, core-hacks

My Website is not working from 3 days boheco.org(magento version- 1.9.3.4)

[image]

Comment: Any One Can suggest me, how can we solve it..

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have cleared the malware on your site on Sept 4th. Now, go to [Google Webmaster's Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console?hl=en) and request a security review. Allow 72 hours, although usually it is completed within 24 hours.

See also my blog for more suggestions on recovery: https://gwillem.gitlab.io/2018/08/30/magentocore.net_skimmer_most_aggressive_to_date/